# Do thermal pads require a burn in period?

Tags: cpu, cooling, thermal-paste, thermal-pads

I just bought a Corsair H105 and it had what I think was a thermal pad on it.

On WIKI it says thermal pads are less efficient then thermal grease, but it seems to be working (30°C-40°C idle 45°C-55°C running a game) but I was wondering if thermal pads require a burn in period to reach their max efficiency?

Comment: It would be unusual for a high performance cooler to use a thermal pad. Why do you assume it's a thermal pad? If you look at the video on the [product page](http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/hydro-series-h105-240mm-extreme-performance-liquid-cpu-cooler) it looks like the "normal" pre-coated thermal paste. As for a burn in, it would depend on the material but is unusual.

Comment: @Seth It was a perfect circle and didn't look moist to me so I assumed it was some kind of pad. At 2:15 of the video on the product page it looks like this [Thermal Pad](https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1nzMOKFXXXXa4XVXXq6xXFXXXT/201101591/HTB1nzMOKFXXXXa4XVXXq6xXFXXXT.jpg)
which is what I got when I looked up thermal pad.

Comment: This really looks like thermal paste, even if it does not look moist.

Comment: The size matters. It's hard to see in the video but if there is almost no height to it, it's likely paste. Thermal pads usually also have some kind of sticky side. If you removed the cooler now you would probably see that it's uneven (don't do this without a reason), something that can't happen with thermal pads. The temps are looking pretty OK. Did you expect it to be cooler?

Comment: @Seth It looked pretty flat so I guess it's paste. I have to remove it soon to change cases, so I'll have to reapply more paste anyways, unless I can manage to take it out connected to the MOBO somehow. I'm fine with the temps, but I plan to try overclocking once I research it more so cooler is better imo. Thanks for the help :D